# wp core update not working anymore

Tags: updates, wp-cli

I have a strange issue. Trying to update core wp version from 4.7 to 4.7.2 but wp keeps saying I am already up to date. But when I run

```
wp core version
```

Then I see 4.7 and not 4.7.2

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot ?

Comment: Have you tried `wp core version --extra`? What do `wp core check-update` and `wp core update` say?

Comment: core check-update just says "You are up to date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is inside your `version.php` file?

```
File: /wp-includes/version.php
1: <?php
2: /**
3:  * The WordPress version string
4:  *
5:  * @global string $wp_version
6:  */
7: $wp_version = '4.7.1';
```

You can play with that number and test.

---

You can try to install the latest version of WP Cli and test.
You may update to WP-CLI version: 1.1.0 if the older version had problems. (I found out you used the 1.0 version of WP-CLI before).

Comment: version.php shows '4.7' which is what wp-cli also returns. But then I cannot update to 4.7.1 for some reason. Wondering if my wp-cli is broken.

Comment: Good thinking. Try with the wp-cli latest version possible. Recently several topics were due to wp-cli not performing well and reinstalling it from scratch it worked.

Comment: yea i just tested with latest version and it worked now. strange.

Comment: @codegeek, would be good if you check the green ✔, just for others who may have the same problem. I really haven't got the idea at first this would be the problem, but I would for sure mention you to reinstall the wp-cli in the later course.

Comment: happy to mark as answer but the issue was that version 1.0 of wp-cli did not work..version 1.1 worked. can you update your answer to just say that ?

Comment: Updated @codegeek. I just mentioned the latest stable version 1.1.0

Comment: Hey. Trying to update an old WP from 4.4 to latest 4.7.x and it says it's up to date. WP CLI is 1.4.1. Any tips? :o